# setting up svn on a FreeBSD server with SSH access

Tags: svn, freebsd

I'm not too familiar with this, and not a network administrator in general, but I am attempting to set up multiuser access to an svn repository on a local server.

So far I have installed subversion via

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/subversion
make install clean
```

Now I'm looking at how to configure and set up repositories and access. I have looked at the greatly useful SVN Book, however I'm looking for any examples/tutorials specific to FreeBSD.

The access to the respositories has to be via SSH.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know how to add users to the system or how to create a repository? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I dont know much at all to be honest!
I have come across http://onlamp.com/bsd/2005/05/12/FreeBSD_Basics.html - its 4 years old so would it still be a relaible source to follow?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you install the port with the svnserve wrapper enabled.

Note: Most--if not all--of the below commands must be executed as root.

Create an svn user group and add all the unix accounts you want to have access to it:

```
pw groupadd <group>
pw groupmod <group> -m <user>[,<user2>,...]
```

Then, create your repository:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repos
```

Change its ownership to the group:

```
chown -R :svngroup /path/to/repos
```

Optionally, remove read-access from 'other' users:

```
chmod -R o-rwx /path/to/repos
```

And change permissions to allow group members sticky (append-only) access to the repository db:

```
find /path/to/repos/db | xargs chmod g+w
find /path/to/repos/db -type d | xargs chmod g+s
```

Test read access by ssh'ing as a user with svngroup membership:

```
svn info svn+ssh://user@host/path/to/repos
```

Test write access by creating your trunk dir (or whatever you want to call it):

```
svn mkdir svn+ssh://user@host/path/to/repos/trunk
```

You may be asked for your ssh password multiple times per svn command if you are not using key exchange.

Comment: A warning for others, pw usermod <user> -G svngroup will for a user that are in other groups, overwrite those other groups. Make sure you do not unintentionally remove users from e.g. wheel. You can use pw usermod <user> -G svngroup,wheel or edit /etc/groups by hand instead.

Comment: Yikes, good catch.  Updated to use groupmod -m.